# Debug android native binaries

Tags: android, debugging, reverse-engineering, reverse

I want to debug an android native binary, i have download gdb from [https://sites.google.com/site/ortegaalfredo/android here](https://sites.google.com/site/ortegaalfredo/android)

but i have this output:

```
root@android:/data/local/tmp # ./gdb /system/bin/ls                            


dlopen failed on 'libthread_db.so.1' - libthread_db.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
GDB will not be able to debug pthreads.

GNU gdb 6.8
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "arm-none-linux-gnueabi"...
(no debugging symbols found)
(gdb) r
Starting program: /system/bin/ls 
(no debugging symbols found)

Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
0x40005a52 in rtld_db_dlactivity () from /system/bin/linker
```

And same error in all binary file

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

As I understand that you have to:

1. upload gdb-server to device (the simple way is set upo you manifest as debuggable true). If you use android stiudio also set up jniDebuggable as true:

   `android{
     buildTypes {
       debug {
           jniDebuggable true
           debuggable true
       }
     }
   }`
2. build your native libs with debug symbols like this one:

   `ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_OPTIM=debug`
3. run you app on device or emulator and invoke from your >project-folder<: `ndk-gdb --verbose`

Comment: I don't have the source code, it's just an binary finding on the net.

Comment: i'm afraid you cannot debug binary without debug information in it